# uWSGI timeout during basic test in tutorial

Tags: uwsgi

I feel so dumb admitting this, but I am struggling on the uWSGI tutorial for Django [here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)

My problem is after making a test.py file as described in the tutorial, and running the command:

`uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py`

I go to port :8000 on the IP adress for my VPS and the connection times out. I have been playing around with nginx and have been able to get the "Welcome to nginx" screen to successfully show itself. The output on my terminal after starting uwsgi with the above command is:

```
    --wsgi-file test.py
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.17.1 (64bit) on [Thu Oct 10 20:58:40 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 10 October 2013 20:17:02
os: Linux-3.9.3-x86_64-linode33 #1 SMP Mon May 20 10:22:57 EDT 2013
nodename: Name
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /usr/local/uwsgi-tutorail/mytest
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 7883
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on :8000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 18638)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:52306 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:13:52)  [GCC 4.6.3]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x26599f0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72792 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x26599f0 pid: 18637 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 18637, cores: 1)
```

I am a complete newb at uwsgi, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure port 8000 is not firewalled in your vps ?

Comment: You started NGINX and UWSGI on the same port?!? Or you're proxying uwsgi through nginx? In this case post the Nginx configuration too.

Comment: alright it looks like I had my firewall to block all traffic from http unless it was on port 8001. I changed my uwsgi command to match 8001. When I visit port 8001 in my browser I get a welcome to nginx message instead of a "hello world" message from test.py. I stopped nginx with the /path/ -s QUIT so I shouldn't be seeing the "welcome to nginx" message right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an elegant solution but I was able to "fix" the problem by rebuilding my VPS and starting from scratch.

Comment: I am very glad that [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html) exists!